# Date comparison in php cannot be done

Tags: php

i cannot compare dates in php.My code look like this:

```
$sqldt="select to_char(sysdate-2,'dd-mon-yyyy') from dual";
$stmtdt = $obj->executeQuery($sqldt);
$rowdt = oci_fetch_array($stmtdt,OCI_BOTH);

$startdate = date('d/m/y', strtotime($rowdt[0]));
$enddate=date('d/m/y');
$workdate=date('d/m/y', strtotime($wdate)); //here wdate is our selected date which is passed from previous page.

echo "start date=".($startdate); //showing correctly

echo "end date=".($enddate);//showing correctly

echo "work date=".($workdate);//showing correctly


$S_WORKDATE=strtotime($workdate);
$S_STARTDATE=strtotime($startdate);
$S_ENDDATE=strtotime($enddate);
```

now when i compare dates like this

```
if($S_WORKDATE<$S_ENDDATE)
{
    echo "worked";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```

whatever comparison like '<' or'>' or '<=' or '>=' is return incorrect result after code execution.please do help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**/** is not work with strtotime() function in dd/mm/yyyy format.

So, You may change **/** to **-**

```
$startdate = date('d-m-y', strtotime($rowdt[0]));
$enddate=date('d-m-y');
$workdate=date('d-m-y', strtotime($wdate));
```

OR u may directly compare like

```
if($workdate<$enddate)
{
    echo "worked";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: An explanation might have helped. `/` __does__ work with strtotime(), but when strtotime() encounters `/` in a 2:2:4 format date it treats the format as US format (`m/d/Y`); when it encounters `-`in a 2:2:4 format date it treats the format as European date (d-m-Y).... as explained in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: @DewDrop Or you could just switch the m and the d around.   It works with slashes,  they just use US notation for the date.  m/d/y

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the code that i have given below,

```
$startdate = new date('d/m/y');
$enddate = new date('d/m/y');
$startdate ->diff($enddate );

if($startdate > $enddate )
echo "startdate  is bigger";
else
echo "enddate  is bigger";
```

**Edited**
Please look at this link for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

I hope this helps you.

Comment: can you please explain this code:    $startdate ->diff($enddate );

Comment: @DewDrop, we are creating two dates directly without using conversion from string to time. Then after that using diff() method of the php that is used to get the difference between the date, and then you can use that returned values to compare which date is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

So basically, your month and day are getting switched around.

You want to use ...

```
$enddate=date('m/d/y');
```